Access a frontend server on EC2 instance
I have created an EC2 with below inbound out bound rules

But I am still not able to access this link from outside the EC2

What am I missing?

The 13.126.125.111:8080 endpoint does not work for me on my computer -- are you sure something is running there? What do you get if you run curl http://13.126.125.111:8080 from your own computer?

May have to double check your web server. Also you shouldn't leave port 22 open to the internet bots will start to brute force that port.

The answer lacks specific steps or details on how to access a frontend server on an EC2 instance. Please provide more detailed instructions or troubleshooting steps.
